# How can I fill holes in Marlite bathroom panels

Tags: hole-repair

We removed some shelves in the bathroom and there are holes in the Marlite . It’s the marbled looking Marlite. We are in our 70’s and don’t want the experience of tearing everything out, just repair it and blend the colors.

Comment: Are the panels textured or smooth?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add pictures of the damage? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: They are smooth. Made to appear marble like.

Comment: Can you hang photos in those areas?

Comment: Ed, I got so disgusted looking at them, I filled them with putty bought a beautiful flowering tree decal and covered them! I do thank you and Jack for trying to help me.